# как связать заметки с пользователем

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Есть приложение asp .net core использующее идентификацию пользователя idenity
В приложении можно создавать и редактировать заметки, теперь вопрос, как сделать чтобы заметки были видны не всем пользователям,  а только тому , который их создал?
то есть мне нужно чтобы я логинился на сайте, и видел бы не все заметки которые существуют, а только те которые я создал, видимо нужно как-то привязывать заметки к айди пользователя, но я не понимаю как
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот картинка моего класса заметки, этот метод не определен
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и так же картинка моего контроллера, мне бы конкретно понять в каком месте делать запрос, и все такое
в общем если не сложно, то прямо с моими именами код бы увидеть, ну и что в него добавить, могу даже дать вот ссылку на гит, там весь код выложен, если кто-нибудь бы показал как и где подправить
было бы супер
https://github.com/SoClose172/RazorWebApp

Comment: делать таблицу с заметками связывать с пользователь по ключу.

Comment: если у вас .net  то думаю вы юзаете Entity framework а там это легко делается. https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.7.php

Comment: Просто там сразу записаны классы и команды и игрока, и я понимаю как к ним обращаться, а так у меня по сути пользователи сразу в бд сохраняются, и я не понимаю каким кодом вытащить айди пользователя, и связывать его с заметками

Answer (score 0):

Добавляете в модель ваших заявок ссылку на пользователя:

```
public class StickyNote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }
}
```

(Не забудьте сделать миграцию)

При получении в контроллере у вас вероятно есть два метода типа "получить список всех заметок пользователя" и "получить заметку по Id".

В первом случае вы делаете запрос фильтруя заметки по id пользователя:

```
var stickyNotes = await this.ApplicationDbContext.StickyNotes
                            .Where(x => x.OwnerId == currentUserId)
                            .AsNoTracking()
                            .ToListAsync();
```

Как вы передадите currentUserId - зависит от вашей архитектуры, обычно как-то так:

```
protected int CurrentUserId => int.Parse(this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
```

Во втором случае после получения заметки будете проверять что есть доступ к данной заметке:

```
var stickyNote = await this.ApplicationDbContext.StickyNotes
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

if(stickyNote.OwnerId != currentUserId)
   throw new Exception("no sticky note with such id");

if(stickyNote.OwnerId != currentUserId)
   throw new Exception("not permitted");
```

Или сразу:

```
var stickyNote = await this.ApplicationDbContext.StickyNotes
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id && x.OwnerId == currentUserId);

if(stickyNote == null)
   throw new Exception("no sticky note with such id or not permitted");
```

Ссылку на метанит вам тоже неплохую дали, почитайте и там.

Comment: не могу вызвать ApplicationUser
у меня можно вызвать applicationid
applicationidenity
applicationexception

Comment: @Антон Подставьте вместо ApplicationUser свой класс пользователя. Штатно это [IdentityUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser(v=vs.111).aspx).

Comment: А как мне понять класс пользователя???
я его сам не создавал, я при создании приложения указал что проверка будет через idenity идти, то есть я класс пользователя сам не создавал, он как я понял создался где-то автоматически, и вот теперь мне нужно понимать где он создался, и из него вот уже вытаскивать

тут важно то- что во всех скинутых мне примерах на метанит например, там в гайде у ребят уже есть и класс пользователя и класс заметки, созданные самим человеком, а так как я использовал шаблон, то не могу понять теперь где у меня этот класс пользователя прописан

Comment: Этот класс стандартный, входит в код одной из подключенных библиотек и там и находится, вам его не видно. Если у вас чистый идентити - пишите IdentityUser, этот класс уже настроен для использования в Identity (проверьте в statrtup.cs строку services.AddDefaultIdentity). Если когда-нибудь понадобится расширить класс пользователя - вам нужно будет создать в папке Models свой класс и указать наследником IdentityUser.

Comment: к сожалению при написании IdenityUser тоже ничего не находит
там возможны только те 3 варианта что я писал выше

Comment: @Антон подключали строку `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;`? Также укажите какая версия asp.net core у вас (какая версия студии), ниже чем 2.1? У вас один проект в solution'е или несколько, если несколько то подключены ли nuget-пакеты, указаны ссылки на проекты?

Comment: нет, не нижу , кор последнего обновления
проблема была в подключении библиотеки в моем классе заметки, получается теперь я добавил в модель моей заметки ссылку на пользователя
иду пробовать дальше сделать так как вы написали

Comment: теперь возникла проблема миграции
как только пытаюсь ее сделать , пишет build failed

Comment: С миграцией разобрался, идем дальше

Comment: Так, остановился на шаге, в котором вы говорите что нужно передать currentUserId, не могли бы вы немного по-подробнее обьяснить куда его передавать, и в каком файле это делается
я так понял что это нужно делать при созданиии заметки?